# How to autoload (reduce import statements) multiple files from the samefolder in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I recently started learning React.js, I wanted to know is there a way to reduce the many import statements while importing different froms from a common folder in react.js.

Like in the below example, I wan to avoid writing multiplle import statements for importing forms because  for the project I have to import more than 100 forms.

```
import React from 'react'

import form1 from './forms/form1';
import form1 from './forms/form1';
import form2 from './forms/form2';
import form3 from './forms/form3';
import form4 from './forms/form4';
import form5 from './forms/form5';
import form6 from './forms/form6';
import form7 from './forms/form7';
import form8 from './forms/form8';
import form9 from './forms/form9';
import form10 from './forms/form10';
import form11 from './forms/form11';
import form12 from './forms/form12';
import form13 from './forms/form13';
import form14 from './forms/form14';
```